# Proving an inequality usuing Lagrange multipliers

Tags: inequality, lagrange-multiplier

Cant seem to find the trick, how to proove this one, usuing Lagrange's amazing multipliers.

$$ \bigg(\frac{x+y}{2}\bigg)^n \le \frac{x^n + y^n}{2} $$

$ x,y > 0$, and $n\in \Bbb N$.

Any tips?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Not sure how to use Lagrange multipliers here. It follows from the fact that $x \mapsto x^n$ is convex (on $(0,\infty)^2)$. You could also try maximizing ${ (\frac{x+y}{2})^n \over\frac{x^n + y^n}{2} }$ over $(x,y) \in (0,\infty)^2)$, and show that the maximum value occurs for $x=y$, with maximum value 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try minimizing $f(x,y) = (\frac{x^n+y^n}{2})$ subject to the constraint $(\frac{x+y}{2})^n = C$, where $C>0$ is a constant.  You should be able to show that when the minimum occurs, $x=y$, which will give you the result you want.

Comment: got it, thanks!